# Is there a different way to bound probability, with no distributional assumptions, other than Markov's inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

I'm having trouble answering this probability interview question from Interview Query:

> Let's say there is man who is 5.10 ft tall who doesn't know how to swim. Let's say he wants to swim in a lake with an average depth of 5.6 ft.
>
> What's the probability of his survival assuming that when the the lake depth surpasses his height, he dies?

My approach thus far has been to use Markov's Inequality to obtain an upper bound on the required probability, i.e. using: $$\Pr[X \ge t] \le \frac{E[X]}{t}$$ letting $X$ be the depth of the lake, $E[X]=5.6$, and $t=5.1$. However, since $t<E[X]$, the right hand side is greater than 1, and we get: $$\Pr[X \ge t] \le 1.098$$ which isn't a useful bound. Is there a better way to answer this question?

Comment: The upper bound is surely 1 as the lake could be uniform depth

Comment: Oh you’ve actually written bound on probability that he dies. It looks good but you’ve misunderstood the units. I suspect they are feet and inches, and 5’10 > 5’6

Comment: The question is unanswerable because any answer from 0 through 1 can be justified (as well as the answer "this is meaningless").  Indeed, the very meaning of "probability" in this setting ought to be challenged: that would demonstrate you are thinking about what makes sense rather than searching for some formula to apply.

Comment: @whuber I don’t think 0 is acceptable - there is a lower bound on probability of survival

Comment: The lower bound is around $6\%$. The ratio of the average depth to the man's height is actually around $0.94$ when one properly takes the ratio of the imperial units. The bound is tight as it can be readily shown to be saturated by a distribution with a lump of probability at $0$ or $\epsilon$ depth and a lump at a finite depth

Comment: @innis In a lake of near-constant depth less than the man's height--assuming (as seems to be intended) that he will survive any depth up to his height--the answer is zero.

Comment: A lake of near constant depth deeper than the mans height would give zero probability of man surviving. But it would violate the constraint that the mean depth is 5’6

Comment: @innisfree Thanks for pointing that out, you're right - I was finding an upper bound on the probability he dies. I also think that the units were indeed misleading, and it should've been 5'10" vs. 5'6". With this, the lower bound on his survival is 6%

Comment: @KyleManning no worries, I encourage you to answer your own question here

Comment: @innis You are positing a situation inconsistent with the problem statement: a lake of near-constant depth whose average is less than the man's height, as indicated in the problem, will present no drowning risk (at least in the extremely naive sense implied by the question). On the other hand, if the man is on an island in the lake and is ringed by water of depth over his head, the drowning risk is 100%. This shows why the answer is indeterminate.